# Upload multiple images with multer from an array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, multer

I've been struggling with how to grab the images in an array of objects that looks like this:

```
const itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    description: { type: String, trim: true, required: true },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    subcategory: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "SubCategory", required: true },
    variations: [
      {
        color: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Color", required: true },
        images: [{ type: Buffer, required: true }],
        sizes: [
          {
            size: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Size", required: true },
            stock: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 }
          }
        ],
        totalStock: { type: Number, required: false, default: 0 }
      }
    ],
    discount: { type: Number, required: false, default: 0 },
    discountPrice: { type: Number, required: false, default: 0 }
    // reviews: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Review" }]
  },
  { toJSON: { virtuals: true }, timestamps: true }
);
```

That is the schema of the object, and i dont know how to add that path for the images in my router, i have it like this:

```
router.post("/api/items", upload.fields([{ name: "images" }]), (async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const obj = req.body;
    const item = new Item(obj);
    await item.save();
    res.send(item);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send("Error while creating item");
  }
}) as RequestHandler);
```

And is always throwing me an "MulterError: Unexpected field"
this is how i send it with postman:

[image: POST]